# Для чего нужен @XStreamAlias в Java?

Tags: java

Для чего в принципе нужен `@XStreamAlias`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^^"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию XStream при сериализации/десериализации объектов и спользует в качестве имени XML-узла полное имя класса.

```
class Foo {
    public String name;
    public Foo(String name) { this.name = name; }
}

Foo foo = new Foo("bar");
XStream xStream = new XStream();
System.out.println(xStream.toXML(foo));
```

Код выше выведет в консоль такой XML:

```xml
<com.example.Foo>
  <name>bar</name>
</com.example.Foo>
```

в большинстве случае вы не захотите видеть полное имя класса в XML. Аннотация `@XStreamAlias` позволяет задать псевдоним для класса:

```
@XStreamAlias("Foo")
class Foo {
    public String name;
    public Foo(String name) { this.name = name; }
}

Foo foo = new Foo("bar");
XStream xStream = new XStream();
xStream.processAnnotations(Foo.class); 
System.out.println(xStream.toXML(foo));
```

Результат:

```xml
<Foo>
  <name>bar</name>
</Foo>
```

Answer (score 2):

Используя `XStream`, `XStreamAlias` указывает как сериализовать класс в xml.

```
@XStreamAlias("student")
class Student {

   @XStreamAlias("name")
   @XStreamAsAttribute   
   private String studentName;

   @XStreamImplicit
   private List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<Note>();

   public Student(String name) {
      this.studentName = name;
   }

   public void addNote(Note note) {
      notes.add(note);
   }

   public String getName(){
      return studentName;
   }

   public List<Note> getNotes(){
      return notes;
   }

   @XStreamOmitField        
   private int type;

   public int getType(){
      return type;
   }

   public void setType(int type){
      this.type = type;
   }
}

@XStreamAlias("note")
class Note {
   private String title;
   private String description;

   public Note(String title, String description) {
      this.title = title;
      this.description = description;
   }

   public String getTitle(){
      return title;
   }

   public String getDescription(){
      return description;
   }     
}
```

Тест:

```
public class XStreamTester {
   public static void main(String args[]){

      XStreamTester tester = new XStreamTester();
      XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
      Student student = tester.getStudentDetails();

      xstream.processAnnotations(Student.class);        

      // пишем объект в xml
      String xml = xstream.toXML(student);
   }

   private Student getStudentDetails(){

      Student student = new Student("Vladislav");

      student.addNote(new Note("first","Моя первая заметочка."));
      student.addNote(new Note("second","Моя втораязаметочка."));
      student.setType(1);

      return student;
   }
}
```

На выходе будет:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <student name="Vladislav">
>    <note>
>       <title>first</title>
>       <description>Моя первая заметочка.</description>
>    </note>
>    <note>
>       <title>second</title>
>       <description>Моя втораязаметочка.</description>
>    </note>
> </student>
> ```

Если, к примеру, у класса `Student` не будет `@XStreamAsAttribute`, то имя будет не аттрибутом, а отдельной нодой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<student>
   <name>
       Vladislav
   </name>
   <note>
      <title>first</title>
      <description>Моя первая заметочка.</description>
   </note>
   <note>
      <title>second</title>
      <description>Моя втораязаметочка.</description>
   </note>
</student>
```

Если не будет `@XStreamAlias("name")`, то будет использоваться имя переменной, а не `name`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<student>
   <studentName>
       Vladislav
   </studentName>
   <note>
      <title>first</title>
      <description>Моя первая заметочка.</description>
   </note>
   <note>
      <title>second</title>
      <description>Моя втораязаметочка.</description>
   </note>
</student>
```